# How to throw test when property is undefined?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I want this test to throw because it doesn't have a username. Instead, it doesn't throw and shows username as undefined.

**Post.js**

```
class Post {

  constructor({username, description, photo}) {
    this.username = username;
    this.description = description;
    this.photo = photo;
  }
}
```

**Post.Test.js**

```
test('post must have a username', () => {
  expect(() => new Post({description: 'a', photo: 'photo.jpg'})).toThrow();
});
```

How do I make it throw?

Comment: The code would not throw an error so it is working as expected. Only way to throw an error is to add code that validates the input and throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fix your class a little bit

```
class Post {

  constructor(user) {
    if (!user.name) throw 'invalid user name'

    this.username = user.name;
    this.description = user.description;
    this.photo = user.photo;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually throw an exception in order for your test to detect one. If you want your application to throw an exception when username is null simply put a null check inside your constructor for whatever values you want to test like so

```js
 constructor({username, description, photo}) {
    if(!username) {
        throw  'Error: Username must not be undefined';
    }
    this.username = username;
    this.description = description;
    this.photo = photo;
  }
```

I would also suggest creating a user domain object and passing that rather than a map object. this will be more reusable later on and is much better practice

```
class User {
    constructor(username) {
    if(!username) {
        throw  'Error: Username must not be undefined'; // put your validation here, now any places with user will throw the error!
    }
    }
}
```

Putting the validation in the User class is good practice as it follows the principle of *high cohesion*, what this means is that each class is **specific** and handles its own logic/ validation independantly.

Lastly i would suggest making your test a bit more precise by checking for the exception message as well as presence. This is very usefull in scenarios where the message is of high importance to users or other areas of the application:

```
test('post must have a username', () => {
try {
 new Post({description: 'a', photo: 'photo.jpg'}))
 fail('No exception thrown with null username!')
} catch(e) {
expect(e.getMessage()).toEqual(expected message.....)
}

});
```